# Adding Data in the datagridview

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have a little problem here, and I admit im not so very good at this but you guyz can help me, right?
so here my problem.
I created this codes:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    connect = new OleDbConnection(coo);
    connect.Open();

    command.Connection = connect;
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    OleDbDataAdapter ODA = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM Items where itemno = '" + textBox1.Text + "'", connect);
    ODA.Fill(dt);
    dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
}
```

which if I click my button "Enter" it can add or can insert data in the datagridview but if I click the "Enter" button again with another data, the previous data I,ve just entered was disappered and replace it with another one and all i want is add an another data by not replacing or deleting the other data i,ve just entered.
What should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [`DataTable.Merge`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk68ew7b(v=vs.110).aspx) will append each successive `DataTable` to the previous one that was assigned to the `DataGridView`, as long as the schema (i.e. column types) is the same.

Replace this:

```
dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
```

With this:

```
if (dataGridView1.DataSource == null)
    dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
else
    ((DataTable)dataGridView1.DataSource).Merge(dt);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need to do a databind. 
Try adding dataGridView1.DataBind() to the end of your code.

Comment: yeah im using databinding but I try to this codes of yours and still not working!